# jQuery event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to trigger a post request when a user clicks the submit button for a comment. Right now clicking the submit button triggers nothing, I even tried to console.log($(this)) I got no output. The first code below is the jQuery event code and ajax code. The block of code below that is the html button. thanks for the help.

```
 $('#submitComment').on('click', '#content', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/comments',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data = { comment: {
                body: $(this).find('input[name="createComment"]').val(),
                user_id: 1,
                image_set_id: 2}
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

the button I am trying to target with jQuery event

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content">
      //the code between comments is in a Handelbar template
        <input name="createComment">
        <button type="submit" id="submitComment">Create Comment</button>
       //end of handelbar template
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Swap `#submitComment` and `#content` in your `.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the delegated handler to an ancestor(`#content`) of the target element(`submitComment`)

```
$('#content').on('click', '#submitComment', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/comments',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data = {
            comment: {
                body: $(this).find('input[name="createComment"]').val(),
                user_id: 1,
                image_set_id: 2
            }
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```